# how to redirect http request to burp proxy with a dns server like dnschef?

Tags: router, burp-suite

I was wondering how an attacker could "own" my network if he got access to my router administration page. I have setup my router dns option to point to my kali-linux box with the dns proxy "dnschef" running. dnschef is able to proxy the dns request without any problem. Now I am wondering How I could redirect all http trafic to a http proxy like burp suite running on my kali-linux box? Should I tell dnscheff to redirect all dns query to the ip adresse of my laptop running kali linux with burp proxy?

Comment: Can you re write this question so its clear.

1. What you want to know.
2. What you use (your setup and software). 
3. Structure the question so its more readable.

Comment: I am eagerly waiting for the answer.